# Local development with VirtualBox and Internet Explorer browsers

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

Has anyone had any issues while setting up their local development system with Mamp Pro 1.8.4, VirtualBox 3.2.8. For viewing websites in IE browsers. I have three websites that I'm looking at all three work in Firefox, Chrome, Safari. For this example lets just say I have:

dev.site1.com
dev.site2.com
dev.site3.com

Now site1 works in IE on VirtualBox well, however Site2 and Site3 display a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error on IE 7, IE 8.

The host file has the following:

192.168.56.1 dev.site1.com dev.site2.com dev.site3.com

I'm using a Bridged Network Adapter for the guest operating system.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just had weird experiences with the Windows hosts file compared to Linux and would suggest just expanding the hosts file to the following:

```
192.168.56.1 dev.site1.com
192.168.56.1 dev.site2.com 
192.168.56.1 dev.site3.com
```